# NetworkManager - segfault

Tags: networkmanager, segmentation-fault

I'm wondering what is causing a segfault within NetworkManager - I see this in dmesg:

NetworkManager[9338]: segfault at 8 ip 0000000000479ef7 sp 00007ffc2607cc10 error 4 in NetworkManager[400000+23b000]

Comment: Um, probably trying to access inaccessible memory? Is it something new you're seeing after an update or something?

Comment: No, I get this repetitively when restarting NetworkManager.  It seems it goes away when I bring the interface down before restarting NetworkManager.

Comment: It's really difficult to debug anything like this when all you know is the name of a program and that it's segfaulting. A name of a Unix would be good to add to the question, along with version of the affected package. If you're able to produce some sort of trace of the program, that would also help. If it is in any way related to [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libnl3/+bug/1539513), then mention that as well.

Comment: Shall I run strace?

Answer (score 1):

A segmentation fault is typically due to a programming error or at least a special case that was not considered appropriately by the developers (e.g. memory allocation that failed, buffer overflow, etc.).

Unless you are one of those, as a mere user there is probably nothing you can do about it except reporting the problem to them. If NetworkManager was provided by your distribution, then it's preferable to report the bug to the package maintainers (i.e. through https://launchpad.net/ for Ubuntu, https://www.debian.org/Bugs/ for Debian, etc.)